# Multiple Multipart file with respective JSON data handling in API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I am trying to implement a REST API where I have to receive multiple file(pdf) along with its related JSON data. I am able to handle a single entity(pdf+JSON), but not sure how to do this for multiple entities. Below are my sample codes:
Controller end-point:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload-multiple")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUploadMultiple(@RequestPart("entities") List<EntityWithFileAndJson> entities) {
        
        if (entities == null || entities.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Please provide a list of entities with files and JSON data.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        
        for (EntityWithFileAndJson entity : entities) {
            MultipartFile file = entity.getFile();
            Fruit fruit = entity.getJsonData();

            if (file == null || file.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Each entity should have a non-empty file.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            // Process the file
            processFile(file);
            System.out.println("============ JSON Data =======================");
            System.out.println(fruit.toString());
        }

        // Return a success message
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Files uploaded and processed successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
```

Model Class:

```
@Data
public class EntityWithFileAndJson {

    private MultipartFile file;
    private Fruit jsonData;

}
```

Postman CURL:

```
curl --location 'localhost:8091/v1/upload-multiple' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.' \
--form 'entities[0].file=@"/home/abcd/Downloads/dummy.pdf"' \
--form 'entities[0].json="{\"id\":1, \"name\":\"apple\"}"' \
--form 'entities[1].file=@"/home/abcd/Downloads/sample.pdf"' \
--form 'entities[1].json="{\"id\":2, \"name\":\"orange\"}"'
```

I am getting below error when I send request through postman:

```
Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.asd.APIDemo.controller.FileUploadController.handleFileUploadMultiple(java.util.List<com.asd.APIDemo.model.EntityWithFileAndJson>): Required part 'entities' is not present.
Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'entities' is not present.]
```

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple files and JSON objects over the wire you should use the media type `multipart/form-data`. Both in the header for sending and as a `consumes` parameter in the endpoint definition. Similar to this:

```java
@PostMapping("/upload-multiple", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUploadMultiple(
                              @RequestPart MultipartFile file1,
                              @RequestPart MyJsonData jsonData1,
                              @RequestPart MultipartFile file2,
                              @RequestPart MyJsonData jsonData2,
                              @RequestPart MultipartFile file3,
                              @RequestPart MyJsonData jsonData3)
```

Maybe you can even manage to get a dynamic list. Honestly I don't have time to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use List of MultipartFile type for the argument annotated with RequestPart and then parse the files into your EntityWithFileAndJson class depending on the format you use to combine the file with the JSON